# Java 8 FunctionalInterface and Interface

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

[image]

Hello guys. What is difference between `FunctionInterface` and `Interface` why we need declare
`@FunctionalInterface` if we have interface in this implementation of package `java.util.function`;

Comment: A functional interface is any interface that contains only one abstract method, but it may contain one or more default methods or static methods. You should study https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach6

Comment: The `@FunctionalInterface` annotation is strictly informational: it's never _necessary_ to use it.  The Java compiler can recognize functional interfaces with or without `@FunctionInterface`.  Just speculating now, but possibly `@FunctionInterface` causes Javadoc to insert the blurb "_**Functional Interface:** This is a functional interface and can therefore be used as the assignment target for a lambda expression or method reference._" in the heading of the method's Javadoc page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FunctionalInterface is an interface with :

- only one **abstract** method.
- zero or several **default** methods (with body).

Thus, the compiler will be able to find the method corresponding to the lambda you will pass.

Eg;

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Supplier<T> {
    T get();
    default String greet() {
        return "Hello, World ";
    }
    default String greet2() {
        return "Hello, World 2";
    }
}
```

Thus java will easily find the right (abstract) method because is is **unique**.

```
        Supplier<Car> fordCarProvider = () -> new Car("Ford", 1500, 4, 43000);
        Supplier<Car> bmwCarProvider = () -> new Car("BMW", 1500, 4, 83000);

        System.out.println(fordCarProvider.get());
        System.out.println(bmwCarProvider.get());
```

But in case you have several abstract method, it is no more a FunctionalInterface. Because ambiguity might occur.

```
// No more @FunctionalInterface
public interface Supplier<T> {
    T get();
    String greet();
    default String greet2() {
        return "Hello, World 2";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@FunctionalInteface` in Java is the `interface` with only one method.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces

Comment: *Clarification:* With only one `abstract` method. It can have other methods, as long as they are `default` or `static`.

Comment: Yep. Default methods could exist

Comment: @Andreas further clarification, exactly one abstract method that does not match a signature of a public method of `java.lang.Object`. But the annotation itself [has a documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) and the language specification [explains it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8), so we don’t need a link to baeldung.com that is infamous for sloppy or outright wrong articles whose sole purpose seems to be to give us more questions on Stackoverflow.